# SSIS Webservice Task Variable

Tags: web-services, variables, ssis

Wonder if someone could help me here. I am trying to download data using Webservice task. The data supplier has a limit of 1000 records per call and asked us to iterate through the whole data set using the "select" and "skip" parameters. "For example to select the first 1000 records in the data set you should set the select parameter to 1000 and the skip parameter to 0. To select the next 1000 records you should set the select parameter to 1000 and the skip parameter to 1000. You should continue to do this until 0 records are returned to you to get the whole data set."

I am not sure how i can implement this in Webservice task using for loop or foreach loop?  any help or tips will be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any options within the foreach loop as the enumerator supports no sort of dynamic HTTP connection. So if it is possible, it should be done somehow using a script task that will defines a list of url's that your loop is able to iterate over, after which for each of the iterations, the url from de dynamic list is linked in a dynamic connection that can be used in the web service task inside the foreach loop.

It might that you want to consider program this task fully in the script task and store the result in a SQL table.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have never used script task before. after reading your response I was brave to give it a go. I managed to add the web reference, added the naming space and copy pasted the sample c# code from here [link](http://www.dotmailer.com/resources/dev-tools-guides/list-of-dotmailer-api-v1-methods/add-contact-to-address-book/). But i am getting a read line the method keyword. not sure where i am going wrong. i need create support ticket with the dotmailer people.